# How to calculate rates from dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I m creating function which will calculate amount  from rate and number of days between dates.

Through loop i need to check which rate is appropriate for v_date.

```
CREATE TABLE INTEREST_RATE_TAB
(

  ID          VARCHAR2(4 BYTE)               NOT NULL,
  NAME          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  RATE          NUMBER                         NOT NULL,
  START_DATE  DATE                           NOT NULL,
  END_DATE     DATE
)


Insert into INTEREST_RATE_TAB
   (ID, NAME, RATE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
Values
   ('1', 'RATE ', 1.2, TO_DATE('01/01/1999 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('12/23/2016 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
Insert into INTEREST_RATE_TAB
   (ID, NAME, RATE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
Values
   ('2', 'RATE II', 0.2, TO_DATE('12/24/2016 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('11/21/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
Insert into INTEREST_RATE_TAB
   (ID, NAME, RATE, START_DATE, END_DATE )
Values
   ('3', 'RATE III', 1.2, TO_DATE('11/22/2017 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

For example :

> if it cover just one period, for example if v_date is 01.01.2000 and
>   v_date_payout is 03.01.2000.  then in loop  will have v_amount = 1.2 *
>   60 (03.01.2000 - 01.01.2000).
>
> but if it covers two or more periods, for example if v_date is
>   12.01.2016 and v_date_payout is 01.01.2018, then loop will have v_amount = 1,2 * 23 (12.23.2016-12.01.2016) and then v_amount = 0.2 *
>   332 (11/21/2017-12/24/2016) and then  v_amount = 1,2 * 39 (01.01.2018
>   - 11/22/2017)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to post what you have tried and where you are stuck. Community expert will help resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you need here.  There is no need for a loop as a single SQL will solve the issue. TIP stop think in terms of procedural steps (ie loops). Instead think in terms of sets of data processed collectively.

The first thing is to realize you have 4 conditions that generate all or part of the desired result. Illustrated below:

```
LET 
  Rs ==> rate.start_date
  Re ==> rate.end_date
  Vd ==> v_date 
  Vp ==> v_date_payout 

Case 1:  Vd>=Rs & Vp<=Re              Days = Vp-Vd
     Rs--------------------------Re
         Vd---------------Vp

 Case 2:  Vd<=Rs & (Vp>=Rs & Vp<=Re)   Days = Vp-Rs
       Rs--------------------------Re
  Vd---------------Vp
  
Case 3:  Vd>=Rs # Vp>=Re             Days = Re-Vd
     Rs--------------------------Re
                      Vd---------------Vp

 Case 4: Vd<Rs & Vp>=Re              Days Re-Rs
       Rs--------------------------Re
 Vd-------------------------------------Vp            

Other Cases: Exhibits 2 cases where Vd---Vp lies totally outside Rs----Re. 
  These will generate NO amount and so not selected for calculation.
             Rs--------------Re
  Vd----Vp                        Vd----Vp
```

The solution involves 2 steps: First, identify the overlap between the range Vd----Ve  and the range Rs------Re. In this step also extract the rate and number of days to apply the rate. Second for each contributing range calculate the partial contribution for each range (can be discarded from final) and the total for the range Vp----Ve.

```
with irt as
   -- resolve null in end_date default to sysdate
   (select id, name, rate,start_date Rs, nvl(end_date,trunc(sysdate)) Re from interest_rate_tab)  
   
   -- generate example v_date, v_date_payout sets
   , vdata as 
   ( select 'v1' vid,date '2000-01-01' Vd, date '2000-03-01' Vp from dual union all
     select 'v2',    date '2016-12-01',    date '2018-01-01' Vp from dual
   )
  
select  t.*
     , days*rate                               range_amount  --contribution of each range
     , sum(days*rate) over (partition by vid)  total_amount  -- for vid total  
  from ( --Determinr Range, extract rate and calculate days to apply rate
         -- Vid, rate, days all that's needed, others included for verification purposes, but can e eliminted from final
         select  vid,Vd,Vp,Rs,Re,Rate                
              ,  case when ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )          then Vp-Vd
                      when ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re)) then Vp-Rs
                      when ( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re)             then Re-Vd
                      when ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re)             then Re-Rs
                      else 0
                 end days
          -- following case staement for display of how daays were derived, for testing, but can e eliminted from fina
             ,  case when ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )
                     then  '( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re ) ==>Vp-Vd'
                     when ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re))
                     then '( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re)) ==>Vp-Rs'
                     when ( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re) 
                     then  '( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re) ==>Re-Vd'
                     when ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) 
                     then '( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) ==>Re-Rs'
                     else 'Error'
                end dd
          from irt
          join vdata 
            on (   ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )           
            or ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re))                           
            or ( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re)                                      
            or ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) 
           )  
      ) t 
order by vid;
       -- resolve null in end_date default to sysdate
       (select id, name, rate,start_date Rs, nvl(end_date,trunc(sysdate)) Re from interest_rate_tab)  
       
       -- generate example v_date, v_date_payout sets
       , vdata as 
       ( select 'v1' vid,date '2000-01-01' Vd, date '2000-03-01' Vp from dual union all
         select 'v2',    date '2016-12-01',    date '2018-01-01' Vp from dual
       )   
    select  t.*
         , days*rate amount_part                   --individual section amount
         , sum(days*rate) over (partition by vid)  --total amount for each vid
      from (
            with irt as
       -- resolve null in end_date default to sysdate
       (select id, name, rate,start_date Rs, nvl(end_date,trunc(sysdate)) Re from interest_rate_tab)  
       
       -- generate example v_date, v_date_payout sets
       , vdata as 
       ( select 'v1' vid,date '2000-01-01' Vd, date '2000-03-01' Vp from dual union all
         select 'v2',    date '2016-12-01',    date '2018-01-01' Vp from dual
       )
             select  vid,Vd,Vp,Rs,Re,Rate                
             -- determine range overlap                 -- calculate days
                  ,  case when ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )          then Vp-Vd
                          when ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re)) then Vp-Rs
                          when ( Vd>=Rs and  Vp>=Re)             then Re-Vd
                          when ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re)             then Re-Rs
                          else 0
                     end days
              -- following case statement for display of how days were derived, for testing, when validated delete
                 ,  case when ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )
                         then  '( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re ) ==>Vp-Vd'
                         when ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re))
                         then '( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re)) ==>Vp-Rs'
                         when ( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re) 
                         then  '( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re) ==>Re-Vd'
                         when ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) 
                         then '( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) ==>Re-Rs'
                         else 'Error'
                    end dd
              from irt
              join vdata 
                on (   ( Vd >= Rs and Vp < Re )           
                or ( Vd<=Rs and (Vp>=Rs and Vp<=Re))                           
                or ( Vd>=Rs And  Vp>=Re)                                      
                or ( Vd<Rs  and  Vp>=Re) 
               )  
          ) t 
    order by vid;
```

And finally a "cleaned-up" version after testing complete.

```
with irt as
   -- end_datesolve null in end_date default to sysdate
   (select id, name, rate,start_date, nvl(end_date,trunc(sysdate)) end_date from interest_rate_tab)  
   
   -- generate example v_date, v_date_payout sets
   , v_data as 
   ( select 'v1' vid,date '2000-01-01' v_date, date '2000-03-01' v_date_payment from dual union all
     select 'v2',    date '2016-12-01',    date '2018-01-01' v_date_payment from dual
   )
  
select distinct vid, v_date, v_date_payment
     , sum(days*rate) over (partition by vid)  total_amount  -- for vid total  
  from ( --Determine Range, extract rate, and calculate days to apply rate
         select  vid,v_date,v_date_payment,start_date,end_date,Rate                
              ,  case when ( v_date >= start_date and v_date_payment < end_date )  then v_date_payment-v_date
                      when (     v_date<=start_date 
                            and v_date_payment>=start_date 
                            and v_date_payment<=end_date
                           )                                                       then v_date_payment-start_date
                      when ( v_date>=start_date And  v_date_payment>=end_date)     then end_date-v_date
                      when ( v_date<start_date  and  v_date_payment>=end_date)     then end_date-start_date
                      else 0
                 end days
          from irt
          join v_data 
            on (   ( v_date >= start_date and v_date_payment < end_date )           
                or ( v_date<=start_date and (v_date_payment>=start_date and v_date_payment<=end_date))                           
                or ( v_date>=start_date And  v_date_payment>=end_date)                                      
                or ( v_date<start_date  and  v_date_payment>=end_date) 
               )  
      ) t 
order by vid;
```